# HTML Email - какую ссылку вставлять на сброс пароля в Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, веб-программирование, вёрстка-email

друзья!
[site_url], [login_url], [reset_pass_url], [user_email], [user_login], [blog_name], [admin_email], [user_id], [custom_fields], [first_name], [last_name], [date], [time], [bp_custom_fields] (buddypress custom fields .. admin only), [post_data] (admin only. Sends $_REQUEST)
Такие переменные есть на сайте, который реализован на CMS Wordpress.
На данный момент занимались редактированием писем, которые приходят при смене пароля и регистрации. По стандарту приходят ссылки. Сейчас сделаны кнопки. Что надо сделать, чтобы всё правильно работало в новом, свёрстаном на HTML письме. Какой URL задавать кнопкам? Заранее извиняюсь за свою глупость и благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала избавьтесь от кнопок в письме, замените их на ссылки и стилизуйте под кнопки. Либо используйте структуру:

```
<a href="">
    <button></button>
</a>
```

Для создания ссылки вам нужно воспользоваться функцией [get_password_reset_key()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_password_reset_key)
Она создаст ключ с базе данных для восстановления пароля пользователем и вернёт его.

Полученную ссылку нужно поместить в href=""